# How to get the callable function defined by exec() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, exec

Say I want to have a function `exec_myfunc` that can execute any user-defined function with an input value of 10. The user is supposed to define the function by a **string** as shown below:

```
func1_str = """
def myfunc1(x):
    return x
"""

func2_str = """
def myfunc2(x):
    return x**2
"""
```

Right now I am using a very hacky way, by extracting the function name between `def`  and `(` using regular expression, as shown below:

```
def exec_myfunc(func_str: str):

    import re
    exec(func_str)
    myfunc_str = re.search(r'def(.*)\(', func_str).group(1).strip()
    return eval(myfunc_str)(10)

print(exec_myfunc(func1_str))
# 10
print(exec_myfunc(func2_str))
# 100
```

I would like to know what is the general and correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly use `exec`:

```
def exec_myfunc(func_str: str):
    fun = {} # to hold your function
    exec(func_str,fun)
    fun_name = list(fun.keys())[1]
    fn = fun[fun_name]
    print(f"The function {fun_name} evaluated at 10 = {fn(10)}")
    
exec_myfunc(func1_str)
The function myfunc1 evaluated at 10 = 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html) module to parse the python string and then find the function name:

```py
import ast

func1 = """
def myfunc1(x):
    return x
"""

parsed_func = ast.parse(func1)

for node in ast.walk(parsed_func):
    if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
        function_name = node.name
        break

print("Function name:", function_name)
```

Prints:

```
Function name: myfunc1
```